# Minimum spanning tree with given edges

Tags: algorithms, minimum-spanning-tree

So the question is:
"Given an undirected graph G=(V,E) with positive edge weights, and E'⊆E, show an algorithm that finds, from all the minimum spanning trees, the one that has more edges from E' ".

Comment: See if slightly changing the weights helps.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? Changing the weights could change the whole spanning tree.

Comment: It’s your exercise...

Comment: It's not "my exercise", I found it online and wanted to solve it, I couldn't so I asked for help. Apparently that is not welcome in here, and I got a downvote like it is a stupid question or something. but your comment "it is your exercise" found to be very helpful here! nice to see this forum is super friendly

Comment: Unfortunately, 90% of questions here are homework exercises, and your question sure looks like one, whether it was actually given to you as an exercise or not.

Comment: Assume for simplicity that the weights are integers. Find a way to slightly modify the weights so that the algorithm still finds a minimum spanning tree, but now has preference for edges in $E'$.

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it, I can't upvote yours for some reason, sorry